# Prevent AWS S3 file upload if Laravel transaction fails

Tags: php, laravel, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to know if there is any way I can prevent a file from uploading to AWS S3 if a transaction in Laravel fails.

For example:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
foreach ($uploaded as $image) {
    DB::table('images')->insert([
       'product_id' => $product_id,
    ]);
    $path = 'path';
    Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs('products', $image->url, $path);
    DB::table('images')
         ->where('product_id', 1)
         ->update([
             'product_id' => $product_id,
         ]);
}
    DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

If the first insert  is successful, the file will be uploaded to the storage even if the update fails. I need to make sure that the whole transaction commits before uploading. (Ignore the code's logic as it is only for demonstration).

One way of doing it is saving the files in another array and uploading them in another loop once the transaction commits, but I would like to know if there is another way of doing it.

Comment: Question. Is `update` only for `id`: 1?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto this is only for demo purpose, ignore the logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an opinion-based question. But I suggest you use queue job, added after `DB::commit()`

Comment: Have you considered having the `catch` block delete the image from S3?

Comment: Move the transaction inside the loop, and move the upload to the end. Then if the queries fail the file won't be uploaded, and if the file upload fails the transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can create a queue job for that after  DB::commit()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).